# Google Charts unsafe-eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have removed `script-src: 'unsafe-eval'` from my CSP headers for security purposes. I have noticed this now broke Google Charts. The chart now fails to render and displays the error:

```
Invalid JSON string: {}
```

Any ideas or is Google just blowing it and allowing unsafe-eval in their libraries? I had the same problem with their Maps and had to go with a different library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Visualization are indeed using `eval()` internally

> Currently Google Visualization API is using:
>   1. eval on corechart.I.js (3 times)
>   2. eval on jsapi

Taken from [**here**](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/978), a bug report regarding GV and Chrome App Manifest v2 compatibility, about 1 month old. Google Visualization does not itself complies with the rules of [**Manifest V2**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2) :

> Is your code or library using eval(), new Function(), innerHTML,
>   setTimeout(), or otherwise passing strings of JS code that are
>   dynamically evaluated?
>
> 1. Use JSON.parse() if you’re parsing JSON code into an object.
> 2. Use a CSP-friendly library, for example, AngularJS.
> 3. Create a sandbox entry in your manifest and run the affected code in the sandbox, using postMessage() to communicate with the sandboxed
>      page.

So google themselves are pretty much aware of the problem.

My impression is that GV internally are using `eval(jsonString)` instead of `JSON.parse()` due to browser compatibility. `JSON.parse()` was not available prior IE8, prior FF 3.1 and so on (see [**compatibility list**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json)), thats why you get the invalid JSON error when you block `eval()` out.

Since this also affects how GV complies to Manifest rules, I guess the issue will disappear very, very soon.

Comment: "Since this also affects how GV complies to Manifest rules, I guess the issue will disappear very, very soon".

18 months later, this still isn't fixed.

Comment: @Flavien,, dont blame me, blame Google

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not blaming you :)